# MT5 Manager API Book MT_RET_ERR_NOTFOUND when calling BookGet Function

Tags: c#, .net, metatrader5

I am developing a custom trading application that uses MT5 Manager API in the backend. I am new to this API and all that I have manage to build I built using the MT5 Api documentation. But I am stuck on implementing the book. I could not find any resources or tutorials on this.
I am using the .Net MT5 Manager Api/sdk.
I am trying to implement the CIMTBook Sink. This is how I have implemented the CIMTBookSink:

```
 public class BookSink:CIMTBookSink
 {
     CIMTManagerAPI managerAPI;
     Helper helper;
     public BookSink()
     {
       
     }
     public MTRetCode Initialize(CIMTManagerAPI manager)
     {
         try {
             if (manager == null) return (MTRetCode.MT_RET_ERR_PARAMS);
             managerAPI = manager;
             helper = new Helper(); 
             return RegisterSink();
         
         }catch(Exception ex) {
             throw;
         }
     }
     public MTRetCode SubscribeBatchAll()
     {
         string[] symbols= helper.FetchAllSymbol(managerAPI);
         var resp = managerAPI.BookSubscribeBatch(symbols,this);
         return resp;
     }
     public MTRetCode UnsubscribeBatchAll() {
         string [] symbols = helper.FetchAllSymbol(managerAPI);
         var resp = managerAPI.BookUnsubscribeBatch(symbols, this);
         return resp;
     }
     public MTRetCode Subscribe(string symbol)
     {
         return managerAPI.BookSubscribe(symbol, this);
     }
     public MTRetCode Unsubscribe(string symbol)
     {
         return managerAPI.BookUnsubscribe(symbol, this);
     }
     public void GetBook(string symbol) {
         MTBook book = new MTBook();
         var resp = managerAPI.BookGet(symbol, out book);
         if (resp == MTRetCode.MT_RET_OK) { 
             Console.WriteLine($"{book.symbol}");
             foreach(var item in book.items.ToArray())
             {
                 Console.WriteLine($"Price: {item.price} Volume: {item.volume}");
             }            
         }
     }
     public override void OnBook(MTBook book)
     {
         try { 
             if (book.symbol != "")
                 Console.WriteLine($"{book.datetime_msc}| {book.symbol} | {book.items_total}");
         
         } catch(Exception ex) { 
             Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
         }
     }
 }
```

To test this I am doing the following:

```
private BookSink book = new BookSink();.
book.Initialize(m_manager);
var book_resp = book.Subscribe("EURUSD");
```

When I run the code and put a debugger on this part to see if the book is getting subscribed properly I get the error MT_RET_ERR_NOTFOUND.
I know the m_manager(CIMTManagerAPI) is initialized correctly, when I initialize the book sink it also return MT_RET_OK. But when I try to subscribe to any symbol I get the error MT_RET_ERR_NOTFOUND. I also know that these symbol names are correct because I am receiving tick data for these symbols.
Am I missing something? Doing something wrong?
Can someone please point me to the right direction because I am honestly clueless about this issue?
Thanks in advance.